# How do I store and retrieve an inputted date using session storage?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

[image]

```js
function storeBooking(
  start
  ) {
  sessionStorage.start = start;
  }
  
  function getBooking() {
    document.getElementById("confirm_start").textContent = sessionStorage.start;
    }
    
  function prefillcard()
{ 
  document.getElementById("start").value =  sessionStorage.start;
  }

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", prefillcard);
```

```html
<form>
<label for="start">Date of birth:</label>
<input type="date" id="start" required="required" name="date of birth" value="2021-10-04" />
<input type="submit" value="Apply">
</form>
```

So what I've basically set up here is for the date of birth to be stored in session storage and then, if the user decides to fill out the form again in the same browser session, it will auto-fill the date of birth in the form.

The only problem is that when I try it, it comes up as `dd/mm/yyyy`, despite it working for other inputted values. The only difference between those and the date of birth is that those were text inputs and this is a date input. How would I go about storing, retrieving, and then auto-filling a form with a date input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.sessionStorage.setItem("Name", Value));` and `window.sessionStorage.getItem("Name");`

In your case using JQuery, you can use your own vanilla js if you are not using JQuery

```
$( "#start" ).on( "change", function() {
  var sdt = $("#start").val();
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("startDT", sdt));
});


function prefillcard() { 
  if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("startDT")) {
   var sdt = window.sessionStorage.getItem("startDT");
   $("#start").val(sdt);
  }
}
```

Non JQuery version

```
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var sdt = document.getElementById("start").value;
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("startDT", sdt));
});


function prefillcard() { 
  if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("startDT")) {
   var sdt = window.sessionStorage.getItem("startDT");
   document.getElementById("start").value = sdt;
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP was using vanilla JS - adding Jquery just for this is not necessary at all

Comment: @aroundtheworld Mentioned that in my answer, and window.sessionStorage.getItem(), window.sessionStorage.setItem() will work fine in vanilla JS

Comment: I was just following the original question: `The only problem is that when I try it, it comes up as dd/mm/yyyy, despite it working for other inputted values.`

To address this in the original code, using `.setAttribute` rather than `.value` is the only change required

Answer (score 0):

Using `setAttribute` should work, so something like:

```
document.getElementById("dateElementID").setAttribute('value', '2021-04-30')
```